# Slow issues with Website running Wordpress on Azure

Tags: performance

I am running a Website with wordpress but I am suffering a slowness issues every three weeks. The website is https://aguadilla.inter.edu/ it is from a University and I am the Webmaster.

Here is GtMetrix report when the website running normal:
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/aguadilla.inter.edu/2XiClnef

Now if I made the test  there is no report, it gave me  the following error:

> Analysis Error
>
> An error occurred fetching the page: read timeout
>
> There may be a connectivity issue between your server and the GTmetrix test server. Please login to try testing from another test location or try again later.
>
> Please see our FAQ on how to fix this error.

Please help.

Jossue Morales
jomorales@ag.inter.edu

Comment: I guess the problem is on your server. How do you fix it every three weeks - by rebooting the server? It might be a memory leak somewhere. I suggest you look at the CPU load and memory usage on the server when you're having problems.

Comment: Your GtMetrix error probably just means that the server was responding too slowly to be analyzed. Was there anything useful in the FAQ it linked you to?